# Change timezone in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want change the default timezone from UTC to Asia/Tehran
where I can change it? 
I tried by changing this code in app.php but it did not work.

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

to

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After update app.php run below command and check

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

You can create below type of route for clear cache in laravel

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {

    $configCache = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    $clearCache = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    // return what you want
});
```

Comment: I can't, Because this project has been implemented on the host
And I do not have access to ssh

Comment: It would be nice if the route is removed afterward or protected by some auth.

Answer (score 21):

go to the file `config/app.php` and look for this entry:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran', //There will be default 'UTC' here
```

As you can see, UTC is a default value for Laravel. So you can easily change it here to, like:

*`'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',`* - See full list [PHP Supported Timezones](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp)

After changes *`app.php`* you should run this command `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 9):

I wonder why Laravel team didn't put this inside *.env*. It seems like best place for parameter like that.

Add this to *.env*:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'put_your/timezone_here'
```

and in */config/app.php* change:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

to:

```
'timezone' => env('TIME_ZONE', 'UTC'),
```

Comment: Probably because your time zone is not likely to change between environments.

Comment: I know, but it's still easier to have 1 config file than 2

Comment: I am more curious why Laravel doesn't respect the value in php.ini, if one exists, first instead of overwriting it with its own?

Comment: Because /config/app.php overrides it anyway. You would have to change it to something like `'timezone' => ini_get('date.timezone') ?? env('TIME_ZONE', 'UTC'),`